# How to highlight particular word of EditText in Android?

Tags: android

I am new to Android, and I am trying to make an application like Word Pad in Android.

How can I highlight (applying colors, changing font styles, bold, italic, underline, etc ...) a selected text in edit text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Spannable spannable=new SpannableString(string);
spannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), start, end, 0);
spannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), start, end, 0);
spannable.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), start, end, 0);
spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), start, end, 0);
editText.setText(spannable);
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Answer (score 0):

visit that page

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html